# How to add model with ImageField using form in a correct way in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a ModelForm containing a field: `image = models.ImageField`:

```
class InstanceForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Instance
        exclude = ('created_at','author',)
```

And my view is:

```
def add_instance(request):
   if request.user.is_authenticated():
      if request.POST:
          form=InstanceForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
          if form.is_valid():
              new_instance=form.save(commit=False)
              new_instance.author=request.user.username
              new_instance.save()
              locals().update(csrf(request))
              return render_to_response(...)
          else:
              return render_to_response(...)
      else:
          form=InstanceForm()
          return render_to_response(...)
   else: return HttpResponse(...)
```

When my form is not valid it shows not only errors, but field 'image' without path to image. It's working in this way, even if I have chosen image at first using `Browse`.

Comment: for uploading file you need to include enctype="multipart/form-data" on form

Comment: I have that line. It's work when I add model with form without mistakes, image upload good.  Only when my form is not valid its desappear

Comment: That's normal. Input fields for file upload don't preserve their value if the form fails to validate. You have to press 'Browse' and chose the file again. There is no way to change this. It is not an issue with Django, but with the HTML specification of WWW Consortium. This is done for security reasons.

Comment: I wrote that is a specification of the W3 Consortium, but I'm not completely sure about it. But the browsers I know don't support this. So there is no way to go around this. If the form fails validation, the user must choose the file again.